# Updating Table with multiple values

Tags: sql

When I run this code

```
UPDATE #YesterdayAssignments
SET ThisWeek = (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM #YesterdayAssignments U
    INNER JOIN vstudyassignments A
        ON U.HHID = A.lhouseholdid
    INNER JOIN tstudies S
        ON S.lstudyid = A.lstudyid
WHERE S.lstudytypeid IN (0,1,2) 
  AND S.bafteruse <> 1 
  AND S.lstatusid = 1 
  AND (A.dmailingdate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
        OR A.dPulledDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
  AND S.dMailingDate < GETDATE()
                GROUP BY HHID
                ) 
FROM #YesterdayAssignments U
    INNER JOIN vstudyassignments A
        ON U.HHID = A.lhouseholdid
    INNER JOIN tstudies S
        ON S.lstudyid = A.lstudyid
WHERE S.lstudytypeid IN (0,1,2) 
  AND S.bafteruse <> 1 
  AND S.lstatusid = 1 
  AND (A.dmailingdate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
        OR A.dPulledDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
  AND S.dMailingDate < GETDATE()
  AND HHID = U.HHID
```

I get the error;

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

I need to update a table with multiple values. Any ideas?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's the query that you are assigning to ThisWeek (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...) that is returning multiple values. So, are you saying that you want ThisWeek to be equal to 3 and 4, for example? :-S

Comment: Without recreating your query, you could simply throw in a TOP 1 between your SELECT and COUNT(*) in the subquery.  You may also need to refine your WHERE clause in the subquery so that only one value is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the query is doing what you think. Try this (freehand):

```
WITH data (Total, HHID) AS
(
    SELECT  COUNT(*),
            HHID
    FROM    #YesterdayAssignments U
            INNER JOIN vstudyassignments A ON U.HHID = A.lhouseholdid
            INNER JOIN tstudies S ON S.lstudyid = A.lstudyid
    WHERE   S.lstudytypeid IN (0,1,2) 
            AND S.bafteruse <> 1 
            AND S.lstatusid = 1 
            AND (A.dmailingdate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
                OR A.dPulledDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1-DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()),GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
            AND S.dMailingDate < GETDATE()
    GROUP BY HHID
)
UPDATE  U
SET     ThisWeek = Total
FROM    #YesterdayAssignments U
        INNER JOIN data D ON D.HHID = U.HHID;
```

The way you have it, you are grouping on HHID which potential returns multiple counts (when there is more than one HHID). So in effect, you are trying to do: `ThisWeek = val1, val2, ..., valN`.

Comment: @Vogtle Glad it works! Feel free to upvote and mark as correct if this solved your problem.